# Call Mockito.verify programmatically

Tags: java, mockito

I have a largish codebase with many decorator classes that usually delegate all but one method to a delegate object, i.e. something like this:

```
class WrapperThing implements Thing{
   private final Thing delegate;
   WrapperThing(Thing thing){this.delegate=thing;}

   public boolean method1(){ return delegate.method1(); }
   public String method2(int arg1, boolean arg2){ return delegate.method2(arg1, arg2); }
   // lots more methods here, all delegating to delegate
}
```

Now I am creating Unit Tests for these wrappers, using a Junit 5 `@TestFactory`, calling each of the methods on the `WrapperThing`, and want to verify that there was an invocation on the wrapped delegate, which is a Mockito mock.

Here's my code so far:

```
private void testMethodDelegation(final Method method) {
    D delegate = mock(delegateType);
    W wrapper = createWrapper(delegate);

    List<Object> args = new ArrayList<>(method.getParameterTypes().length + 1);
    args.add(wrapper);
    gatherMethodArgs(method, args); // populate args with mocks or default values
    try {
        method.invoke(args.toArray(new Object[0]));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        // this is fine, we're just testing the delegation
    }

    // now comes the verify part
    List<Object> mockArgs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        mockArgs.add(verify(delegate));
        mockArgs.addAll(nCopies(args.size()-1, any()));
        method.invoke(mockArgs.toArray(new Object[0]));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }

}
```

When I run this, the error I get is:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at some.packagename.AbstractDelegateTest.testMethodDelegation(AbstractDelegateTest.java:81)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to verify a method call if you don't know the exact method?

Comment: What method is being passed in as the parameter? Looks like you just want to pass either the wrapper or delegate as the first parameter. If so why do you need to verify?

Comment: Oh wait. Are you testing if your methods are delegate methods? Basically "when method A in wrapper is called, method A in delegate is called".

Comment: `method.invoke(method, ...)` doesn't make sense. The first parameter is the object that is invoking the method. It should be `method.invoke(wrapper, ...)` and `method.invoke(delegate, ...)`.

Comment: @George yep, that may be it. long day, sorry

Comment: @George Fixed that bug, but it unfortunately didn't solve my problem, just generated a new error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I was calling method.invoke() wrong.
I thought the format was `method.invoke([target, arg1, ... argn])`, but it is actually `method.invoke(target, [arg1, ... argn])`. It's been a long day, my bad.

This code works:

```
private void testMethodDelegation(final Method method) {
    D delegate = mock(delegateType);
    W wrapper = createWrapper(delegate);

    List<Object> args = new ArrayList<>(method.getParameterTypes().length);
    gatherMethodArgs(method, args); // populate args with mocks or default values
    try {
        method.invoke(wrapper, args.toArray(new Object[0]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // this is fine, we're just testing the delegation
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    callVerify(method, delegate);
}

private void callVerify(final Method method, final D delegate) {
    // now comes the verify part
    List<Object> mockArgs = new ArrayList<>(method.getParameterTypes().length);
    try {
        D verifyDelegate = verify(delegate);
        gatherVerifyArgs(method, mockArgs);
        method.invoke(verifyDelegate, mockArgs.toArray(new Object[0]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}

private void gatherVerifyArgs(final Method method, final List<Object> args) {
    for (Class<?> parameterType : method.getParameterTypes()) {
        if (int.class == parameterType) {
            args.add(anyInt());
        } else if (boolean.class == parameterType) {
            args.add(anyBoolean());
        } else if (long.class == parameterType) {
            args.add(anyLong());
        } else if (double.class == parameterType) {
            args.add(anyDouble());
        } else if (float.class == parameterType) {
            args.add(anyFloat());
        } else if (String.class == parameterType) {
            args.add(anyString());
        } else {
            args.add(any());
        }
    }
}

private void gatherMethodArgs(final Method method, final List<Object> args) {

    int i = 0;
    for (Class<?> type : method.getParameterTypes()) {
        try {
            if (type == String.class) {
                args.add("");
            } else if (type.isArray()) {
                args.add(Array.newInstance(type.getComponentType(), 0));
            } else if (Primitives.allPrimitiveTypes().contains(type)) {
                args.add(Defaults.defaultValue(type));
            } else if (Primitives.allWrapperTypes().contains(type)) {
                args.add(Defaults.defaultValue(Primitives.unwrap(type)));
            } else if (type == List.class) {
                args.add(ImmutableList.of());
            } else if (type == Set.class) {
                args.add(ImmutableSet.of());
            } else if (type == Map.class) {
                args.add(ImmutableMap.of());
            } else if (type.getName().startsWith("java.util.")) {
                args.add(type.newInstance());
            } else {
                args.add(mock(type));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                String.format("Error mocking parameter %d (%s) of method %s", i,
                              method.getGenericParameterTypes()[i], method), e);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```